# Angular directive: whats the difference between scope in controller vs scope in link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

Im learning about Angular `directive`s and I can't wrap my head around the `scope` topic. Suppose I have this custom `directive` which is named `parentDirective`. It has a `controller` property and a `link` property, as follows:

```
angular.module("app").directive("parentDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "dirs/parent.html",
        scope:{
            character: "="
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.getData = function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        },
        link: function (scope,elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind("click", function (e) {
                //get object here?
            });
            scope.getData = function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Its template is defined as follows:

```
<p ng-click="getData(character)">
    {{character.name}}
</p>
```

I can get the `character` object in the `controller` function through the `$scope` variable and I have access to the same data in the `link` function through `scope`. Whats the difference between the two methods in this regard? Second question, Is it possible to bind a `click` to the `directive` and get the object like this:

```
    elem.bind("click", function (e) {
        //get object here?
    });
```

Comment: No difference. It is same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope is specific to current directive instance and is the same object in both functions.

For defining methods on the scope, there's no difference if they are defined in controller or link function, unless there is race condition that requires the method to be defined as early as possible. For this reason it makes sense to define scope methods in controller.

Event handler doesn't differ from any other function, it is

```
elem.on("click", function (e) {
  scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.character...
  });
});
```

`scope.$apply(...)` wrapper doesn't hurt anyway, but the necessity of it depends on what happens with `scope.character`.

The directive can have only `controller` and no `link`. Current Angular versions (1.5+) suggest the style where [`bindToController` + `controllerAs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) are used instead of `scope` bindings as common ground for directives and components.

Then the directive may look like

```
restrict: "E",
template: '<p>{{$ctrl.character.name}}</p>',
controllerAs: '$ctrl',
bindToController: { character: "=" },
controller: function ($element, $scope) {
    var self = this;

    self.getData = function (data) { ... };

    $element.on("click", function (e) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
            self.character...
        });
    });
}
```

`link` function may appear as [`$postLink` controller hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks), but here it is not needed.